# Disabling the dates before selected date and after today date

Tags: jquery

In Reports I am showing the startDate and endDate fields to select the particular dates using jQuery ui datepicker.For the startDate and endDate fields I am giving the today date as the default date. My requirement is

1) If the customer directly clicks in the endDate the dates before today date and after today date should be disable.

2) If the customer selects any particular date for startdate then for enddate the dates before to the selected date and after to the today date should be disabled.

I am using the below code to this.

```
var dates = $( "#startDate, #endDate" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear : true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    maxDate: 0,

    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var option = this.id == "startDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
        instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings );
        dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
      }
  });
```

If I use this I am able to do the second requirement but not the first one. But I need to implement both conditions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, you need to call a function to set min date and max date while you select both start and end date.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/saranyaciet/6F9a5/1/)

```
// To set mindate in enddate
function customRange(input) 
{ 
return {
        minDate: (input.id == "end_date" ? $("#start_date").datepicker("getDate") : new Date())
      }; 
}

// To set maxdate in startdate
function customRangeStart(input) 
{ 
return {
        maxDate:(input.id == "start_date" ? $("#end_date").datepicker("getDate") : null)
      }; 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#start_date').datepicker(
   {
       beforeShow: customRangeStart,
       minDate: 0,
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
       changeYear: true
   });

   $('#end_date').datepicker(
   {
       beforeShow: customRange,
       dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
       changeYear: true
   });
});
```